# How to render Text on custom mesh in unity3d which able to change text content at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have struggle the problem two days ago. Most of solution is use `CanvasRenderer`, I also use it amostly achieve with the minial code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextMeshCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CanvasRenderer CanvasRenderer;
    public Mesh meshModle;//standard Quad mesh just for test

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        this.CanvasRenderer.SetMesh(meshModle);
    }
}
```

But encounter problem is text not refresh when I change Text content.
I also test `CanvasRenderer.Clear()` at up of `SetMesh`, it clear text content, but not show text anymore.

By the way, I have another question, how to custom mesh to fit text rendering?Under Shaded Wireframe editor modle,I have seem every text char rendered as a seperation quad and I'm wonder how does unity engine render text with custom mesh and default(not has custom mesh)? Thanks

Comment: Maybe an option could be to use custom shader to achieve the curve effect you want (don't know much about shaders but I guess it should be doable). Otherwise you could render your text to a texture and apply it to a material (but it would be heavy to do).

Comment: @Kardux, I don't know the curve effect ways.The second way you mentioned does means I should create another camera to collect the text  to a renderer texture?

Comment: I guess there are many way to do it : you could use a font file to create your texture pixel per pixel (this would be a pain in ...) but to me the easiest way would be to hide a _Camera_ and a _Canvas_ somewhere in your scene and use a _RenderTexture_ to paste it on the object with the shape you want to get (be aware that using _RenderTexture_ is heavy).

Comment: @Kardux， I‘m also worry about RenderTexture preference because I will use many custom mesh. Create a static font texture will cost many memory.I think a balanced choice is render font format to a texture at runtime and apply it to custom mesh.

Comment: Yeah, if you're planning on using many custom meshes, this would imply using many _Cameras_ + _RenderTextures_ which would be far too much heavy. I'd recommend looking there for some curved shaders example (the ones from Curved World works great) but I can't do more than leading you there since I'm a complete newbie when it comes to shader writing...

Comment: @Kardux thanks a lot. I will try curved shader~